# Discord bot issue

Tags: discord.py

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OviTv.png)

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl0p1.png)

Please help me!

Comment: The method is called `has_permissions` and not `has_permission`. Just change the name, and you will not get the error.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow, you will have noticed that your question was downvoted to all living hell, that is because your question didn't follow the "how to ask" found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I really recommend you give it a look for your next question :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your using discord py 2.0?, Or old version?, If your using old version of discord py please upgrade

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```